# build-id generation during compilation-linking

Tags: linux, elf

Does anyone now how build-id is generated? I've been looking everywhere online but I can't find an explanation. I found this, https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/RolandMcGrath/BuildID, but that doesn't tell me how it is generated. I also ound this, https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.8.3/source/tools/perf/util/build-id.c, but I'm not sure if this the right place to look at. So, does anybody know how build-id is generated?

Is it generated over a section of an ELF file, multiple sections or randomly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it generated over a section of an ELF file, multiple sections or randomly?

The goal of Build-ID is to make it so that it's easy to associate debug info with the ELF image (`ET_EXEC` or `ET_DYN`) to which it belongs.

As Roland explains, you *could* use a random UUID for it, but that has a disadvantage of precluding bit-identical rebuilds. You *could* also use `md5` or `sha1` checksum over the entire ELF image, but that has a risk of people misusing it as an actual checksum.

So the implementation uses a checksum over *important* parts of the image, such that hash collisions (identical build-ids) over different images are highly unlikely.

Precisely which parts are important is left to linker implementers and is left as an implementation detail. If you wanted to know *exactly* what these parts are, you'll have to read corresponding implementation files for [Gold](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=binutils-gdb.git;a=blob;f=gold/layout.cc;hb=1d4ef7201ffa3174931f36befbe032e0a41836f6#l3410), [BFD ld](https://sourceware.org/legacy-ml/binutils/2007-07/msg00012.html) and [LLD](https://reviews.llvm.org/D18091).

You can also substitute *your own* UUID (if bit-identical rebuilds are not a concern for you) -- the `--build-id` flag accepts user-provided bit string and will happily put it into your ELF image.

P.S. The build-id.c you found in `perf` has nothing to do with *generation* of build-ids. `perf` *records* build-id's of images that it observes, so later analysis can grab correct ELF images to perform symbolization.